# Export a word document as a Test suite into Microsoft test manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, microsoft-test-manager

I have a word document containing some test suites. I would like to export this data into Microsoft test manager using a .net c# program. What libraries and methods can be used to perform this?

Comment: Someone already build this. Check out:SmartOffice from http://www.modernrequirements.com/smartword4tfs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TFS API in order to achieve this, anything displayed in MTM is stored in TFS.
Follow the [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) in order to see reference for the classes and methods.

You may need to put your data into multiple tables as TFS database have different table for everything.